# Alternative/Faster way to model this data

Tags: database, postgresql

Our SaaS app helps eCommerce stores create more effective promotions.  In order to do this, we need to retain quite a bit of data - promotional data plus all the products these promotions are associated with across each customer group that these promotions are applied to. I've normalized this data but I feel one of these tables, promotion_products, might grow too fast and slow down our most critical queries.

Here's how this table gets populated so quickly: If a store has 25,000 products and runs 1 promotion per week across 10 customer groups, then the promotion_products table would have 250,000 new entries/week (1 million/mo). Since this is a SaaS product, we have many customers creating the same amount of data or more.

How can I improve this schema so that the data in the promotion_products can be queried quickly?

```
products
  - product_id
  - customer_id
  - name

promotions
  - promotion_id
  - customer_id
  - promotion (i.e. 20% off etc)

promotion_products (need fast read access)
  - product_id
  - promotion_id
  - customer_id
  - group_id (each offer is associated w/ one or many customer groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've denormalized it a bit by adding customer_id to the promotion_products table, that should help, especially if it's indexed. You could also consider clustering the promotion_products table by customer and promotion_id.

I'm wondering why group_id and customer_id are in promotion_products as it seems to be conflicting in that a group_id seems like it'd relate to multiple customers.

Make sure to index all the fields that you intend on querying by.